# Elegant way to get size and unique count using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID     subject_id
3403       1
3478       1
3478       1
3478       1
3478       1
3478       1
3478       1
3481       1
3481       1
3481       3
3481       3
```

I would like to get the `size()` as well as `no of unique subjects under each ID`

So, I tried the below

```
df['s_cnt'] = df.groupby(['Id']).subject_id.nunique()
df['r_cnt'] = df.groupby(['Id']).size()
```

Is there anyway to do both the operations in a single line?

Any elegant approach would be helpful as I have to apply this on big data

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
 Id   s_cnt   r_cnt
3403    1       1
3478    1       6
3481    2       4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named aggregation, for function `size` is ppossible pass any column, e.g. here `subject_id` or `ID`, but for `nunique` is necessary pass column used for test number of unique values - here `subject_id`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(s_cnt = ('subject_id', 'nunique'),
                                           r_cnt= ('subject_id', 'size'))
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(s_cnt = ('subject_id', 'nunique'),
                                           r_cnt= ('ID', 'size'))
```

---

```
print (df1)
     ID  s_cnt  r_cnt
0  3403      1      1
1  3478      1      6
2  3481      2      4
```

EDIT: For oldier pandas versiond use `reset_index` instead `as_index=False`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').agg(s_cnt = ('subject_id', 'nunique'),
                           r_cnt= ('subject_id', 'size')).reset_index()
```

Comment: Oh wow...you have solution for all pandas problems. fantastic. thanks, upvoted

Comment: If I use the `exact solution as yours`, I don;t see the groupby column `ID`. May I know whty?

Comment: @TheGreat - Because oldier pandas version, give me a sec.